# Class 'Config' not found when moved laravel site over to Centos server

Tags: php, laravel, centos

I currently have a laravel 5.8 instance working on my local machine, I moved the files over to a Staging server that runs on Centos. I recently updated the PHP version there to 7.3 it was at 5.4 Now I'm trying to get the server up and display the webpage but I keep getting a strange error.

I've already restarted the whole server.

I went to /var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:50 (this is vendor files though)

```
    public function report(\Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Exception) {

        $debugSetting = Config::get('app.debug');

        Config::set('app.debug', true);  //<--- This is line 50
        //echo "<pre>" . $e . "</pre>";
        $data = ['content' => $e->getMessage(),'line' => $e->getLine(),'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString()];




        Config::set('app.debug', $debugSetting);
    }

    return parent::report($e);
}
```

If you're familiar with Laravel you would know that Config is a part of the core functionality of the project and for it to not be able to access it means something else is wrong that is making it not to be either set correctly or instantiated incorrectly.

I just tried to run composer update or composer install but this error is also preventing me.

I also checked the httpd/ssl_error_log and it says almost the same error as shown below

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Config' not found in /var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:50\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(314): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))\n#1 /var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))\n#2 /var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/public/index.php(57): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 50
```

My Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Config' not found in 
/var/www/myflexca/public_html/staging/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:50
Stack trace:
#0
/var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminat/ 
Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(367): App\Exceptions\Handle->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#1 
/var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(132): 
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 /var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/artisan(35): 
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), 
Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 {main}
  thrown in 
/var/www/myproject/public_html/staging/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 50
```

## SOLUTION

I fixed this by changing the

```
use Config;
```

at the top to

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
```

It was only followed by more errors but it got past this one.

## REAL PROBLEM

My Laravel dependencies were not up to date. The real solution is to re-install Laravel to get the dependencies.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Comment: I bet if you look at line 50 of `/var/www/myflexca/public_html/staging/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` you'll see your problem.

Comment: Make sure you ran `composer install`.

Comment: @miken32 Sorry I did that, I'll edit the post

Comment: There's a good chance you're experiencing a different root error. Then, your exception handler is throwing a second error when attempting to manage the first. Check your error logs for a previous exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to my problem ended up being for me to reinstall [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation) using

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

It turns out that the server I was moving it to didn't have all of the updated dependencies that was needed for the updated instance of Laravel. Before trying anything else try doing this to see if it needs updating/reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

If you've just changed from PHP version, you probably have vendor files for the older PHP 5.x version that contains legacy/deprecated code for the new versions of PHP 7.x

Based on that, I recommend deleting the `composer.lock` file, the `vendor` folder as well and then, execute composer again with `composer install`.

As the `composer.lock` doesn't exists anymore it'll make a clean install for your new PHP version.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Even if my local machine has PHP 7.x on it and I copied the files from there to the server??? I should still do this?

Comment: Sure. Composer not only install vendor files, it makes some other internal tasks... Who knows

Comment: Thank you, I tried this though and it didn't work. I edited the Config to the location of the Config but now it's screaming that I've registered a new Facade incorrectly so, I'm not sure.